# My fluid domain disappears and appears to turn into the fluid object when I bake

Tags: physics, fluid-simulation

[image]

I made this scene with a fluid simulation a few days ago, but the fluid domain turned into the melt word "ICE" instead of the cube I used as the domain. Is this supposed to happen? Where is the cube domain now and how can I see or edit it again? Even after I click "load start up file" or close the blender and reopen,the domain stay that way in my next project.

Answer (score 5):

### Fluid Domain "Disappears" When Baked

Don't worry, that is what is supposed to happen, even though it may seem odd. When you bake a fluid simulation, the domain object visually becomes the fluid flowing and no longer is visible as the cube domain object you started with:

[image]

But notice that if you want to see the original domain cube again, you can toggle (turn on/off) the visibility of the Fluid property of the domain by clicking on the "Display Modifier" icon ( [image] ) next to the "Fluid" button.

Another way to see the domain object's original shape (geometry) is to set the "Viewport Display" to "Geometry" in the domain's settings:

[image]

In addition, the fluid domain cube is still intact if you want to modify it -- just switch to Edit mode and you can see and edit the cube:

[image]

Comment: You can also set *Display* to *Geometry* in the domain settings.